# Lasso with Coordinate Descent in Scikit-Learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I've tried to implement the lasso regression with coordinate descent. In the later process the objective function will include the first derivative of the function as well. All derivatives are computed by a automatic differentiation tool. In the first step I've tried to implement the lasso with simple cyclic coordinate descent without including the derivative.
In an small example with 4 features and ~100 samples the algorithm is converging to the right solution. But the solutions of my real dataset and the solution of the lasso regression from scikit-learn are diffrent. Furthermore, scikit-learns algorithm converges a lot faster. I've used default settings on the scikit-learn setup.

My question is: What is the diffrence between the defaulth scikit-learn algorithm of the lasso regression and the simple coordinate descent? Is there a paper which describes the implemented algorithm?

BR